# How can I build a decent working Audio Player in Pathfinder?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, magic-items

Inspired by user46844 question [DnD headphones/music for my character?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/127411/dnd-headphones-music-for-my-character). I am looking for a similar device for my pathfinder campaign. I tried to find one without success.

Is there already one somewhere? How can I build a decent working Audio Player in Pathfinder?

Comment: Related to https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/134502/what-device-or-spell-records-audio-visual-evidence

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Welcome to my shop. My name is Bolépo A. Pavel and I have three items for you.

## Ambient Audio Player

You like to hear the sound of the sea or a roaring lion? With this small device it is now possible!
A DM could even allow basic music like minimal or tribal.

Feature:

- Powered by the famous cantrip [Ghost Sound](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/g/ghost-sound/)
- Speaker include
- 360° sound
- Infinite usage
- Command by word ("Play", "Pause", "Stop", "Next")
- Slot: Head

Price: 900gp

## Vocal Audio Player

Are you looking for more? Do you want to unleash the power of vocals? Do you enjoy beatbox? With this small device it is now possible!
A DM could even allow all kind of music.

Feature:

- Powered by the famous spell [Ventriloquism](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/v/ventriloquism/)
- Speaker include
- Infinite usage
- Command by word ("Play", "Pause", "Stop", "Next")
- Slot: Head

Price: 1800po (+ 2sp) (spellLevel * casterLevel * 1800 <=> 1*1*1800)

## Full Audio Player

Not enough? Looking for a premium experience? Here we go.

Feature:

- Powered by the famous spell [Marching Chant](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/m/marching-chant)
- Speaker include
- Infinite usage
- Command by word ("Play", "Pause", "Stop", "Next")
- Slot: Head

Price: 10800gp (spellLevel * casterLevel * 1800 <=> 2*3*1800)

Comment: was the middle cost supposed to be 1800 gp?

Comment: @Ifusaso I added some details. I use the [official formula](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/coreRulebook/magicItems/magicItemCreation.html). I hope I didnt make a mistake.